# Pyside2 and material design

Tags: python, qt, material-design, pyside2

I'm writing a simple app to control an experimental setup. I have most of the important stuff done, and I was thinking that it would be nice to use material design for the UI widgets.

I found this repo that has all the widgets i'd want https://github.com/laserpants/qt-material-widgets, but i have no idea how to import them in my project. I am using Pyside2 and qtDesigner, loading the ui file with QUiLoader, eg:

```
class ConsoleWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self, uifilename):
        super(ConsoleWindow, self).__init__(None)
        self.window = QUiLoader().load( QFile( 'uifile.ui' ) )

        self.setupCallbacks()

        self.window.installEventFilter(self)
        self.window.show()

 [...]
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: That project can not be imported into Python since there is no translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you only have one option to achieve this,
using style sheets for each of the elements you use.

I found an [old repository](https://github.com/martinrotter/qt-material-stylesheet) that tried to provide a set of style rules so you can use them directly into your code, but I don't know how similar they are to a pure-material-design-look.

You can either, set style per elements like:

```
class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        # Changing background color
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0.2, 0.3, 0.8, 0.2);")
```

or load a general style sheet for your application:

```
sheet = ":/some_style_sheet_file.qss"
with open(sheet, "r") as f:
    style = f.read()

app = QApplication([])
# ...
app.setStyleSheet(style)
sys.app(app.exec_())
```

If you want to use Qml on the other hand, you can achieve this easily like [this example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/examples/declarative/textproperties).